# Prove: $\lim _{x \to \infty}\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{1+n^2x^2}=\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$

Tags: calculus

I want to ask you if can it be so simple to prove that $\lim _{x \to \infty}\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{1+n^2x^2}=\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$ by divide the numerator and denominator with $x^2$ and that's it?

If it this simple indeed you can write a comment and I'll delete the question after I'll read it, or perhaps I'm missing something important (and I should involve power series).

Thanks!

Comment: I think it is not enough. For any $x$, the sum with the $x$ stuff is certainly less than $\sum 1/n^2$. But we need to show that for $x$ large, the sum is very little less. So I would take the difference between $1/n^2$ and the same term with the $x$ stuff, and show that for $x$ large the **sum** of these differences is small. Details should not take too long!  I don't see as simple an argument using power series.

Comment: I suggest you check http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105487/uniform-continuity-allows-pushing-limit-inside-integral/105491#105491

Comment: It is always very tempting to want to interchange the series limit and the limit on $x$, but we have to resist the temptation! It is very important to consider uniform convergence (which is one of the main properties that makes power series so very awesome).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use
$$
   \frac{1}{n^2} \frac{x^2}{1+x^2} \leqslant \frac{1}{n^2} \frac{x^2}{x^2 + n^{-2}} < \frac{1}{n^2}
$$
Thus
$$
    \frac{x^2}{1+x^2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} \leqslant \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^2}{n^2+x^2} < \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}
$$
Both upper and the lower bounds have the same limit as $x \to \infty$.

Answer (score 8):

In general, interchanging limits and sums or integrals can be tricky.  It's not always true that
$\lim_{x \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \lim_{x \to \infty} f_n(x)$, even when both sides converge.  It is true for dominated
convergence (if there is some convergent series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ with $|f_n(x)| \le b_n$ for all $n$ and $x$) and monotone convergence (if $f_n(x)$ is positive, and increasing as a function of $x$).  This example satisfies both conditions.

Answer (score 2):

$$ \sum \left( \frac{1}{n^2} - \frac{x^2}{1+n^2x^2} \right) = \sum \frac{ 1}{n^2(1+n^2 x^2) }  \leq \frac{1}{x^2} \sum \frac{1}{n^4} \to 0.$$